# Remove @Spell from a syntax cluster

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm using the [vim-polyglot](https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot) plugin. In the JavaScript filetype plugin file, it configures Vim to run spell checking on strings. After glancing through the plugin's implementation, I can see that does this for the following syntax clusters:

- `jsString`
- `jsTemplateString`
- `jsObjectKeyString`
- `jsObjectStringKey`

[Here's](https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot/blob/35ea4d2b9072594b6c0ccf87bde7978ed9f94755/syntax/javascript.vim#L56) an example of how the cluster is defined:

```
syntax region  jsString           start=+\z(["']\)+  skip=+\\\%(\z1\|$\)+  end=+\z1+ end=+$+  contains=jsSpecial,@Spell extend
```

I've tried adding the lines below to `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` as well as `~/.config.nvim/ftplugins/javascript.vim`, but neither seems to remove the spelling:

```
syntax cluster jsString remove=@Spell
syntax cluster jsTemplateString remove=@Spell
syntax cluster jsObjectKeyString remove=@Spell
syntax cluster jsObjectStringKey remove=@Spell
```

**How can I remove spelling from select syntax highlighting groups provided by vim-polyglot?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not really syntax *clusters*, but simply syntax *items*.

While `@Spell` and `@NoSpell` *are* syntax clusters, what matters with those is where they are contained and not really items they contain, so we can't really use `syntax cluster` to modify those and enable or spelling for existing syntax items...

So your best bet here is really to redefine the syntax items, removing the `@Spell` part of them.

You can redefine only those 4 items, but there aren't really good ways to just modify part of the command (simply removing the `@Spell` part), you end up having to set them from scratch again, which means you have to copy their definition from the original file and then make the modifications.

To add to an existing syntax file, see [`:help mysyntaxfile-add`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#mysyntaxfile-add).

In short, you should create a `~/.vim/after/syntax/javascript.vim` with contents:

```
syntax clear jsString
syntax clear jsTemplateString
syntax clear jsObjectKeyString
syntax clear jsObjectStringKey
syntax region  jsString           start=+\z(["']\)+  skip=+\\\%(\z1\|$\)+  end=+\z1+ end=+$+  contains=jsSpecial extend
syntax region  jsTemplateString   start=+`+  skip=+\\`+  end=+`+     contains=jsTemplateExpression,jsSpecial extend
syntax region  jsObjectKeyString   contained start=+\z(["']\)+  skip=+\\\%(\z1\|$\)+  end=+\z1\|$+  contains=jsSpecial skipwhite skipempty nextgroup=jsObjectValue
syntax region  jsObjectStringKey   contained start=+\z(["']\)+  skip=+\\\%(\z1\|$\)+  end=+\z1\|$+  contains=jsSpecial extend skipwhite skipempty nextgroup=jsFuncArgs,jsObjectValue
```

These commands will first clear the syntax items and then define them again, but this time without including the `contains=@Spell` part, so they'll not enable  spell checking for those rules.

Comment: That did the trick! It's a bummer that there's not an easy way to modify where the `@Spell` cluster is contained. Thanks for the help, and the detailed answer!

Comment: One small note for anyone else who stumbles across this, the file I created was `~/.config/nvim/after/syntax/javascript.vim`, since I'm using NeoVim.